# What is the handgun a companion will term best?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

So, I'm trying to decide what handgun to stock ammo for, for Raul Tejada, but I don't know what calibre because I'm not sure what handgun he'd take over his own .44 mag. What handguns/lever-action rifles will he switch too, even unmodified, over his own .44?

Comment: don't remember companions needing ammo

Comment: @paralytic They do if you give them a gun other than their standard.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter what gun you choose to give him, because you can take it from his inventory and then what ever gun you give him, he will use it

Answer (score 0):

For me, he would use the Brush Gun, A Light Shining in Darkness, and the Assault Carbine. Not saying that's all he will use,because I haven't tried everything...